# FileNotFoundException when trying to pass txt file as parameter for method in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner, java-io

all! I'm having an issue with Scanner/passing a text file as the parameter for a method. If I create a Scanner in main, I can do everything just fine.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File file = new File([FILEPATH]);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
...
```

However, when I try to pass the text file to a method and create a Scanner there, I get a FileNotFoundException

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File file = new File([FILEPATH]);
        method(file);
    }

    public static String method(File file){

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file); //This is where I get the error :(
...
```

The prompt for the problem specifically says that the parameter must be a file, so I can't change it to a String parameter to pass the file path instead.

I used .getPath() to make sure the file path for the file within my method matches the file path for the file in main, and it does. I'm not sure what needs to be fixed. Would greatly appreciate any help!

EDIT; Adding screenshots with my full code and output from each version so people can verify my changes.

[Main: Working Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3lUC.png)
[Method: Non-working Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoTki.png)

Comment: Verify that the file you're trying to open actually exists at the specified path. If the file doesn't exist, you will get a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: You need to add the complete stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: Hello, @OwaisYosuf! The file indeed exists at the specified path. I believe the code would fail from both main and the method if that wasn't the case. For some reason, it only gives me this error in the latter.

Comment: Hard to believe. Impossible, actually. You changed something else along with the code.

Comment: But the code looks fine. Do one thing check the path you specified. Print the complete path on console.log and cross check it once. May be there is some issue.

Comment: Does any part of your code renames or deletes the file before the scanner is created?

Comment: Add `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()+" "+file.exists());` once in `main()` before you call the method and once in your method before you create the `Scanner`. This will help you in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @user207421 I've added screenshots so you can verify my changes!

Comment: @ThomasKläger It just returns the file path I already had and "true"

Comment: @RifatRubayatulIslam I don't think so. I double checked to make sure the variable names stayed the same. I added screenshots of my code to the original post if you'd like to take a closer look.

Comment: Your screenshots don't prove that you didn't delete or move the file.

Comment: @user207421 Not really sure if there's anyway to prove that. I don't really gain anything from this if that were the case.

Comment: Your screenshot says you have compilation error. You have not handled the `FileNotFoundException` thrown by the `Scanner`. Wrap it inside `try-catch` or add `throws` to your method declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Did you read the error message carefully?

It doesn't say "file not found" - it says: "Unresolved compilation problem: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException".

This is because `new Scanner(file)` is declared to throw a `FileNotFoundException` and your `method()` must either handle that exception or declare that it possibly throws a `FileNotFoundException` (by declaring it as `method(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {...}`

Note that declaring the method as `method(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {...}` delegates the obligation to either handle the exception or declare it as thrown exception to the caller of `method()`. That means that in turn your `main()` method has to either handle the `FileNotFoundException` or you need to declare your `main()` method as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {}`)
```

---

Why does the compiler not complain for version that works?

This is because in the version that works you declared the `main()` method as `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {}` - the Java compiler is happy with that: that declaration tells it that any Exception thrown within the body of `main()` is acceptable.

Comment: Shouldn't the code still execute, though? I didn't add the throws to the one that works, and it still prints the string. The one with the method doesn't execute at all, even after adding the throws. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmThe.png

Comment: @ant I've updated my answer with more information about how you need to change your main method and why in the version that works it does work.

Comment: @ant No, it shouldn't execute, and it didn't, and you should have fixed the compilation errors before trying, and you should have noticed the rather telling phrase 'unresolved compilation problem' when you did so.

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting an FileNotFoundException, you just have an unhandled checked exception. You should handle the exception for the code to compile using try-catch block or throws.

Comment: I added the throws FileNotFoundException and I'm being told I still have an unhandled exception type? https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmThe.png

Comment: The 'throws' just propagates the exception handling responsibility to the calling class. Now you'll have to handle the exception in the main class.
`try{
decode(file);
} catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
}`

Comment: In the `main()` *method.* It is hard to believe this code ever compiled at all. Impossible, actually.